# How to open Scaffold's Drawer on page load?

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

Logging into our Flutter app opens to dashboard that has a Scaffold with a Drawer full of menu items.

I'd like to perform some A/B testing with having the Drawer open on page load or at least animating the Drawer being opened immediately on load.

I'm aware of `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()` but I'm not sure where to place this code so that it will run immediately after the build() method. I'm also not aware of any fields on either Drawer or Scaffold which would load with the Drawer open.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wait after the first frame is loaded.

```
    _onLayoutDone(_) {
       //your logic here

    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onLayoutDone);
      super.initState();
    }
```

I wrote a post about this, you can take a look if you want : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly along with a passed in key to the Scaffold and then _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();

Comment: `Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold`. Didn't work for me.

Comment: The error says you are using a scaffold from different context, check your code

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onLayoutDone);` should be in the `build` method.

Answer (score 4):

Override `initState`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // use this
  Timer.run(() => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store a state variable to hide and show drawer - `isDrawerBeingShown`.

Based on the state variable toggle the state of drawer. It is set to false by default so it will be displayed for the first time.

`void _showDrawer(BuildContext context) async` it must be marked as async so that it runs after build method.

Create `showDrawerUtility` method to show drawer on demand when ever required.

**Edit:**

Use GlobalKey

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();


class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  MainScreen({Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => new MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  bool isDrawerBeingShown;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isDrawerBeingShown = false;
    _showDrawer(context);
  }

  void _showDrawer(BuildContext context) async {
    if(!isDrawerBeingShown) {
     _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      setState(() => isDrawerBeingShown = true);
    }
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // build method goes here}
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting trick with async but it doesn't seem like the state has been completely initialized yet as I get a NoSuchMethodError: The method 'openDrawer' was called on null. I may be missing something however.

Comment: I updated the code with GlobalKey to access the state of the Scaffold Widget. @GregNoe Please check if it works.

Comment: I tried both key and Scaffold.of(context).closeDrawer() earlier and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

follow my code

```
    import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

    class openDrawerOnLoadPage extends StatefulWidget {
      openDrawerOnLoadPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _openDrawerOnLoadPageState createState() =>     _openDrawerOnLoadPageState();
    }

    class _openDrawerOnLoadPageState extends State<openDrawerOnLoadPage> {

      late bool isDrawerBeingShown;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        isDrawerBeingShown = false;
        _showDrawer(context);
      }

      void _showDrawer(BuildContext context) async {
        if (!isDrawerBeingShown) {
          EasyDebounce.debounce('openDrawer', Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              () async {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
            setState(() => isDrawerBeingShown = true);
          });
        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).